# What happens if the last two teams from the UCL pot are draw together in the round of 16, but they are from the same country/group?

Tags: football, champions-league

If teams from the same country or group cant be draw together, so what if the last two teams available are from the same country or group? Do they redraw it? As far as I know, they move on to the next team, but what if there isn't any available?[image]

What do we do in this situation? Real Madrid and Atletico are the only options left, but they are from the same country

Comment: The knockout stage does not use a Pot 1/Pot 2 draw system. Your example makes no sense, as explained in the answer by dly, and I would suggest removing it entirely.

Answer (score 3):

The Round of 16 draw is not like any other draw you might know.

The draw will be held as follows:

1. Every group winner has a dedicated bowl containing 8 balls with their name in it.
2. There is one bowl containing all runners-up.
3. A runner-up is drawn.
4. A computer checks the possible opponents and a ball from each of their bowls will be placed into an empty bowl and shuffled. This way no ineligible opponents can be drawn.
5. If only one possible opponent for a team remains the match will be placed directly.

To see how it's done you can watch last year's draw on YouTube:

Comment: I edited it, could you pls look again. I don't think I got my question answered.

Comment: @HosseinHatami  as I've said the computer regularly checks all possible outcomes (or at least they say so). You even have three runners-up from La Liga in the last three games, which would be extremely rare. Normally the computer would do as I stated under 5 and draw directly once there is no more than one possibility left for any of the teams. How it would end up in a three way tie - I don't know for sure. From my understanding from previous draws Porto would have only Spanish teams in their bowl (or just draw Real directly) to keep Dortmund, City and Bayern for the Spanish runners-up.